# How to detect NVIDIA GPU and jump to driver website programmatically

Tags: windows, driver, nvidia

I'm using CUDA in my application and are dependent on the installed CUDA driver. So at the beginning of the application I'm able to check all preconditions

- get the CUDA/GPU device
- check the compute capability
- get the installed driver

and then inform the user if some conditions are not met. Only the driver version bugs me a little. I can show the user which version is required and guide him to the nvidia website. Afterwards the user needs to select the GPU and the windows version.

But many customers are not aware and inexperienced what to do and we get many calls what to select on the website. So what I wanted to do is that I can at least preselect what they need to download, which means I preselect the graphics device and the windows version.

Of course the best option would be that can download the driver directly without going to the website.

So here's my question:

- Is there a way to preselect the driver required options on the website if you know your GPU?
- Or is there a way where I can download the driver directly without having to go to the website?

Answer (score 0):

See [the following answer](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-detect-nvidia-gpu-and-jump-to-driver-website-programmatically/251542/2) from [@MarkusHoHo](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/u/MarkusHoHo) on the Nvidia developer forum:

> Sadly the answer to both is no.
>
> Of course there might be ways to automatically handle these kind of Web forms through scripting or other means.
>
> But there is no officially supported API for the download page and most importantly no guarantee that it might not change at any time.
>
> I am sorry if this does not help, but I hear your comment regarding people being confused on the download page and I will pass that one internally.